# Where does non-reduced root system come up?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

A reduced root system $R$ (over $\mathbb{R}$) is one which satisfies the condition that $\mathbb{R}\alpha \cap R $ consists of only $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ for every root $\alpha$ (following Bourbaki's definition of root system). I know that the reduced root systems come up from the root space decomposition of a semisimple lie algebra. Are there subjects where the non-reduced root systems also make a natural appearance?

Comment: They naturally arise as roots sytems  of finite dimensional simple superalgebras. For example, the root system of type $BCn$ is irreducible but not reduced

Comment: Are these lie superalgebras or just superalgebras?

Comment: Also the Lie superalgebra $B(0,n)$ from the Kac list of simple Lie superalgebras has the non-reduced root system of $BC(n)$-type.

Answer (score 3):

More precisely you should write that reduced root systems come up in the classification of *split* semisimple Lie algebras. If your ground field $k$ is not algebraically closed, a semisimple Lie algebra typically has two root systems attached to: Its "absolute" root system, which is the one you get after scalar extension to an algebraic closure, and which by the classical theory  is always reduced, and its $k$-*rational* (or *relative*) roots, which are the roots for a maximal *split* toral subalgebra (which is no longer necessarily maximal toral). Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497093/96384) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2548338/96384).

These $k$-rational roots in a certain sense are a quotient of the absolute root system; they can be empty, or form a root system which possibly is non-reduced.

For the base field $k=\mathbb R$, I gave a list of simple Lie algebras where the relative roots form a system of type $BC$ in [Examples of Lie algebras of the $BC$ root system type](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3132957/96384).